# Azure In-Role Cache Retirement

Tags: azure, azure-in-role-cache

Microsoft announced that as of November 30,2016, "the Managed Cache Service will be shut down, and the In-Role Cache service will no longer be supported". My app uses an in-role cache for session storage and it still functional. The app is slated to go offline March 31, 2017. Does anyone know if the in-role cache in Azure will remain functional, even if not supported, for some period of time?

Comment: That would be a question for Azure support, either via comment on their blog posts, [twitter](https://twitter.com/azure), etc. There's really no way to answer future product support questions here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if the in-role cache in Azure will remain functional,
>   even if not supported, for some period of time?

Yes, it will continue to work but not supported. This is based on the comments posted on the [`blog post announcing the retirement`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-managed-cache-and-in-role-cache-services-to-be-retired-on-11-30-2016/):

[image]